# Simple sql query work in sql but not work in python mysql

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have a simple query

```
select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') as cur_date
```

It work in my sql client tool but not work in python MySQLdb call.

It show error TypeError('not enough arguments for format string',)
'%' character python understand as sign query input paramenter .
How escape my sql query?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Maybe include the failing code in the question, along with a proper traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace '%' to '%%' like: sql = sql.replace("%", "%%")